# MySQL: problems to my Django app if upgrading ubuntu from 10.04 to 12.04?

Tags: mysql, django, ubuntu, upgrade

I elaborate. I have a Django app that uses MySQL. I wanted to upgrade MySQL from 5.1 to 5.5, but my Ubuntu version is 10.04 and I have heard that I need version 12.04 to install MySQL 5.5. Therefore, I need first to upgrade Ubuntu and then upgrade MySQL, right? Now my question:

Can I have any problem in my Django app (conflicts, code incompatibilities...) if I upgrade Ubuntu? I guess not, but I need to be sure before I break the app.

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you upgrade to a two-year-old version of Ubuntu, rather than the latest?

Comment: Good question... Ok, let's upgrade to 13.10 (latest version, isn't it?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will not issue.
Just make sure you are having same python version at new Ubuntu as you were having previous.
And also i will suggest you to update Ubuntu at most latest version and as i know 12.04 is not latest one.